# Dagger throws error if fragment implements a custom interface

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, dagger

I have a simple interface, that one of my fragments implements it:

```
interface ExitWithAnimation {
var posX: Int?
var posY: Int?

fun isToBeExitedWithAnimation(): Boolean
}


class MoreInfoFragment: Fragment(), ExitWithAnimation {

override var posX: Int? = null
override var posY: Int? = null

private var foodItem: FoodItem? = null

override fun isToBeExitedWithAnimation(): Boolean = true

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(exit: IntArray? = null, foodItem: FoodItem): MoreInfoFragment = MoreInfoFragment()
        .apply {
        if (exit != null && exit.size == 2) {
            posX = exit[0]
            posY = exit[1]
        }
        this.foodItem = foodItem
    }
}}
```

However, I get a lot of error when compiling:

```
/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:6: error: <identifier> expected
public final class MoreInfoFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment implements com.mehdi.challange.lifesum.view.interface.ExitWithAnimation {
                                                                                                                       ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:6: error: illegal start of type
public final class MoreInfoFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment implements com.mehdi.challange.lifesum.view.interface.ExitWithAnimation {
                                                                                                                                ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:6: error: ';' expected
public final class MoreInfoFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment implements com.mehdi.challange.lifesum.view.interface.ExitWithAnimation {
                                                                                                                                                  ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
    private final int[] exit = null;
    ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:12: error: illegal start of expression
    private final com.mehdi.challange.lifesum.model.FoodItem foodItem = null;
    ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:13: error: illegal start of expression
    private java.util.HashMap _$_findViewCache;
    ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:17: error: ';' expected
    public java.lang.Integer getPosX() {
                                    ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:22: error: ';' expected
    public void setPosX(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
                       ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:23: error: ';' expected
    java.lang.Integer p0) {
                        ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:28: error: ';' expected
    public java.lang.Integer getPosY() {
                                    ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:33: error: ';' expected
    public void setPosY(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
                       ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:34: error: ';' expected
    java.lang.Integer p0) {
                        ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:38: error: ';' expected
    public boolean isToBeExitedWithAnimation() {
                                            ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:44: error: ';' expected
    public android.view.View onCreateView(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                         ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:45: error: <identifier> expected
    android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
                                         ^/Users/mehdisatei/lifesum/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/mehdi/challange/lifesum/view/MoreInfoFragment.java:45: error: illegal start of expression
    android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
```

When I remove the interface implementation, it works fine. Any idea why this happens? I don't even use any Inject in this fragment. Appreciate any help in advance

Comment: doesn't look like a Dagger issue

Answer (score 0):

It was a Dagger issue but fixed when clean and rebuild